# NavigationMixin not working on community

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, customer-community, experience-cloud, navigationmixin.navigate

I want to navigate from `lwc` component `firstComponent` to a community page `enerie test`.

**FirstComponent**

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class FicheNutrition1 extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
...
handleLevier1Click() {
        console.log('this is levier 1');
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'energie_test__c'
            },
        });
        console.log("##############");
    }
...
}
```

API name of the page: `energie_test__c` . it contains a custom lightning component. I tried navigating to the component first but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `comm__namedPage` use the `name` attribute

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'comm__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        name: 'energie_test__c'
    },
});
```